# DOM Manipulation not working inside Template Literals

Tags: javascript, dom

Start DOM:

```
var group = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group');
var p = group[0].getElementsByTagName('p');
```

**NOT working code:**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= p.length; i++) {
`this is : ${p[i].innerHTML}`;}
```

**working code:**
had to do like this to access innerHTML:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= p.length; i++) {
console.log("this is : "+ p[i].innerHTML +"")}
```

actual code is long since i want to loop multiple innerHTML from different tag.
Since i cant access via template literals format, had to do typical console.log way.

Is it really not possible or i missed something there?

FULL HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="mb-1">
        <h4 class="mb-3" style="font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; color: rgb(99, 57, 145); font-size: 20px;">Where i can use Prepay to secure my payment?</h4>
        <p class="light-font mb-5" style="color: rgb(149, 144, 148); font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Prepay works just like online banking, you can send to anyone, anywhere like online marketplace (mudah,carousell etc), online gaming and when you dealing with online services where you need to pay your money in advance.</p>

        <h4 class="mb-3" style="font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; color: rgb(99, 57, 145); font-size: 20px;">My shipment was lost/damaged during delivery by Prepay Courier, What should I do?</h4>
        <p class="light-font mb-5" style="color: rgb(149, 144, 148); font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Every courier delivery has been insured with amount up to RM200, contact us to proceed for a claim.</p>

        <!-- TOO LONG, I JUST CUT THESE 2 ABOVE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share the html

Comment: @brk done. the idea is to loop h4 and p tag. so i can use it into new code structure without manually copy 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `i <= p.length;` to `i < p.length;`

```js
var group = document.getElementsByClassName('form-group');
var p = group[0].getElementsByTagName('p');


for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  console.log(`this is : ${p[i].innerHTML}`);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="mb-1">
    <h4 class="mb-3" style="font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; color: rgb(99, 57, 145); font-size: 20px;">Where i can use Prepay to secure my payment?</h4>
    <p class="light-font mb-5" style="color: rgb(149, 144, 148); font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Prepay works just like online banking, you can send to anyone, anywhere like online marketplace (mudah,carousell etc), online gaming and when you dealing with online services where you need to pay your money in advance.</p>

    <h4 class="mb-3" style="font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; color: rgb(99, 57, 145); font-size: 20px;">My shipment was lost/damaged during delivery by Prepay Courier, What should I do?</h4>
    <p class="light-font mb-5" style="color: rgb(149, 144, 148); font-family: Rubik, Lato, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">Every courier delivery has been insured with amount up to RM200, contact us to proceed for a claim.</p>


  </div>
</div>
```